# How can I get my html to display my django model?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get my django model to be shown in the footer of my base.html but I can't get it to show up. I've looked at a few videos and I can't figure out where I'm going wrong. I know that the model works as I've made 4 entries in my database and I can view them on the admin page. The code also doesn't show any errors so I have nothing to go off of there. Here it is:

Models.py

```
class SocialMediaPlatform(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    font_awesome_class = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    base_url = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, 
    default='https://instagram.com/ or https://tiktok.com/@')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.base_url
```

Views.py

```
def social_media_base_view(request):
    context = {}
    smbase = SocialMediaPlatform.objects.all()
    context['smbase'] = smbase

    return render(request, 'base.html', context)
```

Urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.social_media_base_view),
]
```

Admin.py

```
@admin.register(SocialMediaPlatform)
class SocialPlatformAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('name', 'font_awesome_class', 'base_url')
```

base.html

```
{% for smlink in smbase %}
    <a href="{{ smlink.name }}">
        <i class="{{ smlink.font_awesome_class }}">
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: you don't need the `SocialMediaPlatform` in `smlink.SocialMediaPlatform.name`...just `smlink.name` etc should work. This "works" but produces no output because django templates silently ignore any missing/invalid properties when accessed inside template `{{ variable.interpolation.blocks }}` for...reasons.

Comment: @Shabble Thanks but I tried that initially and it didn't work. I just tried it again and it still isn't working any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Look what you are passing as context:

```
def social_media_base_view(request):
    ...
    smbase = SocialMediaPlatform.objects.all()
    context['smbase'] = smbase
    return ...
```

It's `QuerySet` of `SocialMediaPlatform` objects. It means, that you can render them one by one with `for` loop:

```
{% for smlink in smbase %}
    {{ smlink.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

You don't need to call `SocialMediaPlatform` model additionaly.

Comment: I believe I made the changes you mentioned but they didn't seem to work but I think I'm getting confused. You said I had a queryset of SocialMediaPlatform and that I didn't need to use SocialMediaPlatform. So did you mean I had to remove the SocialMediaPlatform lines and make another change or just that one?

Comment: @Keegan Is `base.html` included in `index.html`? You can firstfully check if you can render `{{ smbase }}` anywhere in `index.html`. You don't need to mention `SocialMediaPlatform` in template.

Answer (score 0):

in your view you use:

```
return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

i can not see, if you are defined `index.html`
Somethere in index you should have

```
{% extends base.htm %}
```

The second, i am agree with @Shabble:

```
{% for smlink in smbase %}
    <a href="{{ smlink.name }}">
        <i class="{{ smlink.font_awesome_class }}">
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

The last:
Try to use Django-GCBV `TemplateView`. Or `ListView`, in your case it is better:

## somethere in views.py

```
Class MyListView(ListView):
    model = SocialMediaPlatform
    template_name = index.html
```

## somethere in urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', MyListView.as_view()),
]
```

## somethere in index.html

```
{% for smlink in object_list %}
    <a href="{{ smlink.name }}">
        <i class="{{ smlink.font_awesome_class }}">
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that doesn't seem to have fixed the issue. In case I added the code wrong, the current code is in my next comment. I also changed it to reference base.html to keep it consistent with my post. I also had to edit your suggested code slightly to make the code run.

Comment: Views.py `class MyListView(generic.ListView):
    model = SocialMediaPlatform
    template_name = 'base.html'


def social_media_base_view(request):
    context = {}
    smbase = SocialMediaPlatform.objects.all()
    context['smbase'] = smbase

    return render(request, 'base.html', context)` Urls.py `path('', views.MyListView.as_view()),` Base.html `{% for smlink in smbase %}
            <a href="{{ smlink.name }}">
                <i class="{{ smlink.font_awesome_class }}">
            </a>
        {% endfor %}`